# Export dataset to Excel or CSV in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I created a report via SSRS and my tablix contains values/fields from a data set and holds other sub reports.

When I export as Excel/CSV ,I am getting all this in One Excel sheet. I JUST need to export all the values from dataset (even if i'm not showing them on my tablix ) and **don't** want export any headers or sup report contents or anything else.

Is there any way i can accomplish this via SSRS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export all the columns from SINGLE dataset into CSV in SSRS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236045/export-all-the-columns-from-single-dataset-into-csv-in-ssrs)

Comment: Why did you just delete your latest question? It wouldn't have been too hard to turn it in to a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no setting like that available. You would need to create a separate report that shows all the data. You could call it the export friendly version.